# @Nested class takes default application.properties values

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, application.properties

Could you tell me why if I have integration test like:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.application.environment=dev"})
@SpringBootTest
class IntegrationTest  {

@Autowired
PropertyConfig propertyConfig;

@Nested
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.application.environment=dev", "spring.application.property=example"})
class ServerLoadConfiguration  {
    
    @Test

    void exampleTest() {
String someProperty = propertyConfig.getSomeProperty(); // old value
        ....
    }
}
```

for exampleTest I get values of properties from 'default' properties instead of overridden with that one property specified in @TestPropertySource spring.application.property?

If I make `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.application.environment=dev", "spring.application.property=example"})`  on IntegrationTest level, then nested class have this value applied.

Comment: As `ServerLoadConfiguration` is not `static` it will contain a  `IntegrationTest .this`, which is what you are probably experiencing. Make it `static`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I get "Only non-static nested classes can serve as '@Nested' test classes " also I won't be able to use @Autowired objects from `IntegrationTest`

Comment: @xerx593 it's just an example.

Comment: @xerx593 then I guess it would not work if I would put this annotation on outer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, cannot reproduce, with:

1. With [simple(st) quickstarter](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.5&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo)
2. Simple (java>16) props:

   ```
   package com.example.demo;

   import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

   @ConfigurationProperties("my")
   record PropertyConfig(String foo) { }
   ```
3. Simple(st) Config:

   ```
   package com.example.demo;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableConfigurationProperties(PropertyConfig.class)
   public class DemoApplication {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
     }

   }
   ```
4. Test:

   ```
   package com.example.demo;

   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
   import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
   import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

   @SpringBootTest
   @TestPropertySource(properties = {"my.foo=bar"})
   public class DemoApplicationIT {

     @Autowired
     private PropertyConfig my;

     @Nested
     class InnerDefaultIT {

       @Autowired
       private PropertyConfig myInner;

       @Test
       void testInner() {
         Assertions.assertNotNull(myInner.foo());
         Assertions.assertEquals(my.foo(), myInner.foo());
       }
     }

     @Nested
     @TestPropertySource(properties = {"my.foo=baz"})
     class InnerIT {

       @Autowired
       private PropertyConfig myInner;

       @Test
       void testInner() {
         Assertions.assertEquals("bar", my.foo());
         Assertions.assertEquals("baz", myInner.foo());
       }
     }

     @Test
     void testOuter() {
       Assertions.assertEquals("bar", my.foo());
     }

   }
   ```
5. Passes (as "unit" as "integration"):

   ```bash
   Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
   ```

Comment: nah. This property has special meaning in application so I have not confused annotations.

Comment: Okay. I got it why it works for you, because you have used @Value. I use @Autowired on record which is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myfoo")
@ConstructorBinding` inside. If I use @Value then I got updated value, but if I refer to this object then I got old value and propably that's because object was initialized once at start. Am I right?

Comment: I've updated question how it looks. Please, take a look.

Comment: please note the significance between `myFoo` and `myInnerFoo` (tests) (if you'd `@Autowired PropertyConfig propertyConfig;` on nested/inner level, I'd expect new value, too)

Comment: I would too, but it's not. If I debug without additional `@Autowired PropertyConfig property config;` then I get old values in getter method. If I add additional @Autowired, then I git new value, BUT inside some other beans I got not refreshed value, so application get wrong results.

Yes. This class is @ConfigurationProperties as I typed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358115/nested-class-takes-default-application-properties-values/74359273?noredirect=1#comment131275231_74359273

Comment: Other services depends on this PropertyConfig and it got not refreshed value as other services were loaded in another spring context initialization I guess.

Comment: so I need to add additional @Autowired variables for other objects or reload context somehow.

Comment: yes, of course! since handling "immutable objects" (like record in my sample) ..on "singleton objects"(initliazed once, always reused) and doing such (grave) things like `@TestPropertySource`, i wouldn't try it otherwise.. :)

Comment: Okay then. We got the solution. My fault that I've missed it in question (about @ConfigurationProperties). Thanks for help :)